# Using JavaScript to add elements to a html multilevel list

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, appendchild

I'm working with JavaScript and HTML and I would like to be able to add user input to a multilevel list in HTML. I have started by making a multilevel list in HTML. As an example I have made a list with Dog information.

```
<div>
<h3> Dogs </h3>
<ul id="myList">
    <li><b>Dog Breeds</b>
        <ul>  
            <li class="facts"> There are a approximately 340 recognized breeds.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><b>Dog Fur</b>
        <ul>  
            <li class="facts"> Depending on the dogs, there are a lot of different kinds of fur.</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Underneath this list I have made 2 fields which can hold userinput and a button next to it which can add the typed in information to the list. My code for the button and type fields is the following:

```
<input type='text' id='input' placeholder="Title"/>
<button type="button" id="add">Add new dog fact</button><br>
<textarea id="input2" rows="5" cols="18" placeholder="The dog fact.."></textarea>
```

In order to add the input to the list, I have written this piece of code:
"myList" is the id I have given the unordered list.

```
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
        var title = document.getElementById("input").value;
        var description = document.getElementById("input2").value;
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = title + description;
        document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(li);
        document.getElementById("input2").value = ""; // clears the value
        document.getElementById("input").value = ""; // clears the value
```

My problem now, is that it will not be structured as I would like. 
By using the code above, the output will be as following if I type in "Dog Size" as title and "Dogs can be both large and small." as the description:

Dog SizeDogs can be both large and small.

instead of:

Dog Size
Dogs can be both large and small.

Does anyone know how to change this, so the user input will be structured the same way the rest of the list is? So that the description will be nested within the title? I'm aware that it is because I have defined "li.textContent" as "title + description", I just don't know how else to add the description data. I have tried to create 2 new list elements in the javaScript code, but this just, as expected, creates 2 new list elements and then I tried to style the description-element with "title.style.listStyleType = "none";", but if I place it in the function, then the entire functions stops working. I'm very confused, and if anyone is able to help me I would be very grateful! Thank you :)

Comment: Think about the structure you've created in HTML:
`<li><b>Title</b><ul><li>Dog Fact</li></ul></li>`.

How would you replicate that when building the element in your JavaScript function?

Comment: To be more direct - you have a single list item element. If you want it to be structured the same way, you'll need to create a `b` element, a `ul` element, and and `li` element in addition, and put them together in the same way.

Although you can use `document.createElement()` for each of these, it may be easier to use the `innerHTML` property of the first list item, as [random](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862133/random) has mentioned.

Comment: I know your new, but after you have got your head around this you might want to look at jquery and knockout. Jquery is a library to make this stuff a bit easier and knockout is really good with this kind of html list manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

use `innerHTML` and add `<br>` between `title` and `description`.

```js
document.getElementById("add").onclick = function() {
  var title = document.getElementById("input").value;
  var description = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.innerHTML = title + "<br>" + description;
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById("input2").value = "";
  document.getElementById("input").value = "";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3> Dogs </h3>
  <ul id="myList">
    <li><b>Dog Breeds</b>
      <ul>
        <li class="facts"> There are a approximately 340 recognized breeds.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><b>Dog Fur</b>
      <ul>
        <li class="facts"> Depending on the dogs, there are a lot of different kinds of fur.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<input type='text' id='input' placeholder="Title" />
<button type="button" id="add">Add new dog fact</button><br>
<textarea id="input2" rows="5" cols="18" placeholder="The dog fact.."></textarea>
</div>
```

Instead of using `onclick`, use `addEventListener` and if you want to add the `description`(as `ul`) under the `title`, below is the code.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('#myList');

document.querySelector('button#add')
  .addEventListener('click', function() {
    const title = document.querySelector('#input').value;
    const description = document.querySelector('#input2').value;

    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = `<b>${title}</b>`;

    const ul = document.createElement('ul');
    const childli = document.createElement('li');
    childli.textContent = description;
    ul.appendChild(childli);

    li.appendChild(ul);
    list.appendChild(li);
  });
```

```html
<div>
  <h3> Dogs </h3>
  <ul id="myList">
    <li><b>Dog Breeds</b>
      <ul>
        <li class="facts"> There are a approximately 340 recognized breeds.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><b>Dog Fur</b>
      <ul>
        <li class="facts"> Depending on the dogs, there are a lot of different kinds of fur.</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<input type='text' id='input' placeholder="Title" />
<button type="button" id="add">Add new dog fact</button><br>
<textarea id="input2" rows="5" cols="18" placeholder="The dog fact.."></textarea>
```